# Bounding box extraction

Tags: python, bounding-box

I am having some trouble with a function I found for generating the xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax located in a `.xml` file. I am not sure why is it not working and I feel like it's a simple mistake that I am not considering.

```
def extract_boxes(self, filename):
        
        # load and parse the file
        tree = ElementTree.parse(filename)
        # get the root of the document
        root = tree.getroot()
        # extract each bounding box
        boxes = list()
        for box in root.findall('.//bndbox'):
            xmin = int(box.find('xmin').text)
            ymin = int(box.find('ymin').text)
            xmax = int(box.find('xmax').text)
            ymax = int(box.find('ymax').text)
            coors = [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]
            boxes.append(coors)
        
        # extract image dimensions
        width = int(root.find('.//size/width').text)
        height = int(root.find('.//size/height').text)
        return boxes, width, height


bbs = extract_boxes(r'C:\Users\name\Desktop\kangaroo-master\annots\00001.xml')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-b6a299d4377e> in <module>
     23 
     24 
---> 25 bbs = extract_boxes(r'C:\Users\name\Desktop\kangaroo-master\annots\00001.xml')
     26 
     27 

TypeError: extract_boxes() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'
```

Comment: It appears that you're defining `extract_boxes` as if it's within a class, but you didn't actually put it inside a class.

Comment: Ahh yes, I did pull it from a class. So I shouldn't need the `self` argument? And I am not quite familiar with what the `ElementTree.parse` is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the mistake. I did not import Element Tree in and needed to remove `self` because I originally pulled the code from a class, but am not using it in a class anymore.

````
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def extract_boxes(filename):        
    # load and parse the file
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    # get the root of the document
    root = tree.getroot()
    # extract each bounding box
    boxes = list()
    for box in root.findall('.//bndbox'):
        xmin = int(box.find('xmin').text)
        ymin = int(box.find('ymin').text)
        xmax = int(box.find('xmax').text)
        ymax = int(box.find('ymax').text)
        coors = [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]
        boxes.append(coors)
        
    # extract image dimensions
    width = int(root.find('.//size/width').text)
    height = int(root.find('.//size/height').text)
    return boxes, width, height


bbs = extract_boxes(r'C:\Users\zlesl\Desktop\kangaroo-master\annots\00001.xml')```
````